# Python: Summing a pig tuple containing float values

Tags: python, tuples, apache-pig

I'm fairly new to Pig/Python and in need of help. Trying to write a  Pig Script that reconciles financial data. The parameters used follow a syntax like (grand_tot, x1, x2,... xn), meaning that the first value should equal the sum of remaining values.

I don't know of a way to accomplish this using Pig alone, so I've been trying to write a Python UDF. Pig passes a tuple to Python; if the sum of x1:xn equals grand_tot, then Python should return a "1" to Pig to show that the numbers match, otherwise it returns a "0".

Here is what I have so far:

```
register 'myudf.py' using jython as myfuncs; 
A = LOAD '$file_nm' USING PigStorage(',') AS (grand_tot,west_region,east_region,prod_line_a,prod_line_b, prod_line_c, prod_line_d); 
A1 = GROUP A ALL; 
B = FOREACH A1 GENERATE TOTUPLE($recon1) as flds; 
C = FOREACH B GENERATE myfuncs.isReconciled(flds) AS res;
DUMP C;
```

**$recon1** is passed as a parameter, and defined as:

```
grand_tot, west_region, east_region
```

I will later pass **$recon2** as:

```
grand_tot, prod_line_a, prod_line_b, prod_line_c, prod_line_d
```

Sample row of data (in **$file_nm**) looks like:

```
grand_tot,west_region,east_region,prod_line_a,prod_line_b, prod_line_c, prod_line_d
10000,4500,5500,900,2200,450,3700,2750
12500,7500,5000,3180,2770,300,3950,2300
9900,7425,2475,1320,460,3070,4630,1740
```

Lastly... here is what I'm trying to do with Python UDF code:

```
@outputSchema("result")
def isReconciled(arrTuple):
    arrTemp = []
    arrNew = []
    string1 = ""
    result = 0
    ## the first element of the Tuple should be the sum of remaining values
    varGrandTot = arrTuple[0]
    ## create a new array with the remaining Tuple values
    arrTemp = arrTuple[1:]

    for item in arrTuple:
        arrNew.append(item)

    ## sum the second to the nth values
    varSum = sum(arrNew)

    ## if the first value in the tuple equals the sum of all remaining values
    if varGrandTot = varSum then:
        #reconciled to the penny
        result = 1
    else:
        result = 0

    return result
```

The error message I receive is:
        **unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'array.array'**

I've tried numerous things attempting to convert the array values into numeric and convert to float so that I can sum, but with no success.

Any ideas??? Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in PIG itself.

First, specify the datatype in the schema. PigStorage will use bytearray as default data type.Hence your python script is throwing the error.Looks like your sample data has int but in your question you have mentioned float.

Second, add the fields starting from the second field or the fields of your choice.

Third, use the bincond operator to check the first field value with the sum.

```
A = LOAD '$file_nm' USING PigStorage(',') AS (grand_tot:float,west_region:float,east_region:float,prod_line_a:float,prod_line_b:float, prod_line_c:float, prod_line_d:float); 
A1 = FOREACH A GENERATE grand_tot,SUM(TOBAG(prod_line_a,prod_line_b,prod_line_c,prod_line_d)) as SUM_ALL; 
B = FOREACH A1 GENERATE (grand_tot == SUM_ALL ? 1 : 0); 
DUMP B;
```

Comment: This works, with a few tweaks. Performance has improved without Python too (a bonus). Thanks.

Comment: @JaneQDoe Cool.Please mark it answer if it answered your question

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely, that your `arrTuple` is not an array of numbers, but some item is an array.

To check it, modify your code by adding some checks:

```
@outputSchema("result")
def isReconciled(arrTuple):
    # some checks
    tmpl = "Item # {i} shall be a number (has value {itm} of type {tp})"
    for i, num in enumerate(arrTuple):
        msg = templ.format(i=i, itm=itm, tp=type(itm))
        assert isinstance(arrTuple[0], (int, long, float)), msg
    # end of checks

    arrTemp = []
    arrNew = []
    string1 = ""
    result = 0
    ## the first element of the Tuple should be the sum of remaining values
    varGrandTot = arrTuple[0]
    ## create a new array with the remaining Tuple values
    arrTemp = arrTuple[1:]

    for item in arrTuple:
        arrNew.append(item)

    ## sum the second to the nth values
    varSum = sum(arrNew)

    ## if the first value in the tuple equals the sum of all remaining values
    if varGrandTot = varSum then:
        #reconciled to the penny
        result = 1
    else:
        result = 0

    return result
```

It is very likely, that it will throw an `AssertionFailed` exception on one of the items. Read the
assertion message to learn, which item is making the troubles.

Anyway, if you want to return 0 or 1 if first number equals sum of the rest of the array, following
would work too:

```
@outputSchema("result")
def isReconciled(arrTuple):
    if arrTuple[0] == sum(arrTuple[1:]):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

and in case, you would live happy with getting `True` instead of 1 and `False` instead of 0:

```
@outputSchema("result")
def isReconciled(arrTuple):
    return arrTuple[0] == sum(arrTuple[1:])
```